# How to fix that issue: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder! [eclipse]

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dx

I did a game without programming (on buildbox) and I would like make the apk, but, when I put on Eclipe, this message appear: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!

I'm using Eclipse 3 neon, I downloaded Android SDK tools, Java SE binary.
I installed the Android SDK plataform-tools (revision 26), the SDK tools is revision 25.2.5, the build tools is revision 26, 25.0.3 and the 21.1.2.
I unistalled the revision 26, but doesn't worked, I changed the project build target to Android 5.0.1 (because is API 21, that's why I installed the build tools 21).
I tried a lot of things that I saw on internet, but it's the same.
I cleaned project, ignored the lint preferences too, but nothing changed.

This is the message I get:

Remembering that I deleted the folder 26.0.0 and I copy the dx file from build tools to plataforms too...

[image: [1]]

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered this problem and found a solution.

The error says that it can't load dx.jar from 26.0.0 build tools, so I uninstalled it from SDK Manager and installed 23.0.0 build tools.
You should keep only 23.0.0 build tools; if you have other versions of the build tools just uninstall them.

I also uninstalled Android 8 (API 26) SDK Platform and
installed Android 7 (API 24) SDK Platform.

After that, I tried compiling. Eclipse didn't find build tools 26 but found 23, and build tools 23 worked fine, so it compiled my Android app.